# How to keep code collapsed when saving in Visual Studio Community 2015?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 for a JavaScript project.

VS allows to collapse or expand functions and regions of code when developing but I have notice that as soon as I save the file, all code is being expanded.

I would like to change this behavior and instead keep the code without automatically expansion.

Any idea how to configure VS?